# Why does my code return this error: mysql_query() access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password no)

Tags: php, mysql

```
</div>
    <div class="items">
        <ul>
            <li>
            <?php echo $msg[$lang]["gtd"]; ?>
                <div class="text">
                    <strong>
                    <?php
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM games WHERE `starttime` > ".(time()-86400));
                        echo mysql_num_rows($result);
                    ?></strong>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Line 8 of this code returns the error:

```
mysql_query() access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password no)".
```

Comment: The message seems clear enough. Double-check your connection information.

Comment: did you even connect to the db first? and which API is used?

Comment: The mysql_ interface functions are deprecated. New development should use either PDO or mysqli.

Comment: If you require any further assistance, please include all relevant code to the matter, ie. database connector. As it stands right now, you haven't provided enough information for us to go on.

Comment: @Marcus after fixing it and adding the connection to the database, I am now receiving this error: Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'a5760312_csgodep'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/a5760312/public_html/index.php on line 3

Comment: Please add your full connection code to your original post. You can leave out the actual password by just replacing it with ***** or something. But only *you* know for sure if the database credentials are actually correct. You need to verify them in your database admin.

Answer (score 2):

[https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_query%28%29+access+denied+for+user+%40%27localhost%27](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_query%28%29%20access%20denied%20for%20user%20%40%27localhost%27)

This is an extremely popular issue on both SO, as well as [Google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22mysql_query()%20access%20denied%20for%20user%20%27%27%40%27localhost%27&oq=%22mysql_query()%20access%20denied%20for%20user%20%27%27%40%27localhost%27&aqs=chrome..69i57.256j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

You don't appear to have connected to the database at all. Include the following (populating the function arguments with your credentials, of course):

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'db_username', 'db_password')
    or die('connection problem:' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('your_database', $connection);
```

Comment: `mysql_select_db('your_database');` that may need to read as `mysql_select_db('your_database', $connection);` - Then again, they might be forced to use the MySQLi or PDO API.

Comment: Could be anything really. From one of the Q&A's I found (on Stack), OP could be mixing MySQL APIs, as per this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/15015031/ - It's anybody's guess though, as they didn't post enough information to support the question.

Comment: Agreed. Seems OP has abandoned ship. Nothing more to see here lol

Comment: We can't save them all Marcus, but can provide assistance to the best of our knowledge with what we're given to work with. *Cheers*