# Receiving the error: "Access denied for user 'a5760312_csgodep'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" more info inside

Tags: php, mysql, database

I receive the message when going to my website:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'a5760312_csgodep'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/a5760312/public_html/index.php on line 3

Connection problem:

> Access denied for user 'a5760312_csgodep'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

How can I fix this?

The line (3) in question is:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'a5760312_csgodep', 'mypassword')
```

(the password is changed for security purposes) 
Any help/solution is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try to change localhost with 127.0.0.1, also go in your db manage page and look if the user 'a5760312_csgodep' exist and has the correct password

Comment: @sdrabb The password is definitely correct, and I changed "localhost" to " 127.0.0.1" to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my code return this error: mysql\_query() access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password no)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518022/why-does-my-code-return-this-error-mysql-query-access-denied-for-user-loc)

Comment: Try to keep just a single question open. This allows others to see what has already been tried/tested/not worked/etc. Opening a duplicate question will not necessarily get your answer any quicker.

Comment: Does the user `a5760312_csgodep` have privileges to access the database in question?

Answer (score 1):

`GRANT INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE ON your_database.* TO 'a5760312_csgodep'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';`

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Does the user `a5760312_csgodep` have permissions to access the database you're trying to work with? When you create a database user, you must also assign them permissions to any given database. Did you not do this?

Comment: As you can probably tell, I am completely new to this. I am using 000webhost and created the mysql database and the database and user with created. How would I assign permissions to the user? Through phpMyAdmin?

Comment: After granting these permissions it says I do not have access to grant these permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the reason that your mysql server password for this user is not set (has not given a password). So you can try out the following connection method.

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'a5760312_csgodep', '');
```

Or else you can use the following query to change the password of your mysql user

```
ALTER USER user IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

This should be run on mysql server

Comment: what is your mysql version?  It works fine with mysql 5.7